# I cannot get passenger to run a Rails 4.2.2 application on Dreamhost

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, dreamhost

I am trying to get Passenger (through DreamHost) to fire up a basic Rails 4.2.2 application. First, phusion passenger gives a syntax error:

"gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc" that views the ':' as an unexpected end of input error.

I removed this gem from the file, and then I begin to get bundler version errors relating to the current bundler version being 1.0.15, while Rails 4.2.2 is dependent on -v >1.3, <2.

By the way I have checked most of the documentation, most of it seems to be somewhat out of date (using Rails ~v 3, ruby 1.8).

Am I missing something vitally important? I uploaded via FTP, and I am not using Apache or nginx development environments. It seems to me this is some sort of module/version error related to bundle? How do I fix this?

One error message:

```
compile error
/home/toccatanosferatu/toccatanosferatu.com/Gemfile:12: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc
                                   ^ (SyntaxError)
  /home/toccatanosferatu/toccatanosferatu.com/Gemfile:12:in `evaluate'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:124:in `load'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158
```

This instance occurs when i remove 'sdoc' from the gemfile, the symbols which cause the original exception to be raised. This exception also causes a browser crash.

```
----Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.2) depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.0.15)

 (Bundler::VersionConflict)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:151:in `resolve'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you post most of the relevant code

Comment: Edit your original question instead of commenting

Comment: Rails 4.2 doesn't run on ruby 1.8 you will need to upgrade your version of ruby and will need upgraded version of bundler as well.

Comment: my version of ruby is 2.2, I think the problem is that my versions are up to date, while dreamhost's are not. Is there a way to use a different version for production configuration?